# High dimensional linear regression inference

Tags: mathematical-statistics, inference, lasso

I am reading through high-dimensional literature currently but I got confused. Especially about statistical inference with LASSO, anyone can clarify me the main difference among

Van De Geer(2014)ON ASYMPTOTICALLY OPTIMAL CONFIDENCE REGIONS AND TESTS FOR HIGH-DIMENSIONAL MODELS

Belloni(2014) Inference on treatment effects after selection amongst high-dimensional controls.

Lee (2016) Exact post-selection inference, with application to the lasso.

I somehow can get that they have different target or methodology. But can someone tell me which one shall we prefer and why?